# How to avoid substitution variables like ":20" and "&" in oracle. while passing them as string variable in insert script

Tags: oracle11g

I want to insert a xslt value in to a clob datatype column.
The xslt contains fields like ':20:' and &xa . 
I'm using set define off; 
and passing the xslt as q['...'].

Still it is showing a error that bind variable 20 is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus:

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
SELECT 'blah \& blah' AS DES FROM DUAL;
```

If you are using other tool, there are a number of approaches you can use.

Use google to search for oracle+using+ampersand+colon+in+sql

Comment: i'm using sql developer tool. if i'm using set escape on; it is showing a message window for substitution value for #xa: